# I need a COUNTIF function that searches a column on a different sheet that contains a question and returns the number occurrences of a specific answer

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have pre and post survey data for a classes my company runs that I want to process on a google sheet. Those surveyed are asked a question and have a set number of responses. What I have been doing is using a COUNTIF, going to the column that contains my question, and counting the occurrences of various responses. But I see a problem in the future when surveys are changed, adding any columns to the sheet that stores the data ruins this method. I *want* a COUNTIFS (I think this is the best function for this) that searches for the column that contains my question, counts the occurrences of whatever response I'm looking for, and returns that number.

I've attached a mockup of the actual spreadsheet. Some of the values are changed but the cell references are the same.
['Table Data'!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TwUu.png)
['Pre Survey Data'!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGPMR.png)

*=COUNTIFS(Substitute(Address(2,11,4,,"Pre Survey Data"),"2","") & ":" & "K", B32)*

This is the formula I've got so far. B32 contains the response I'm trying to count within the column I want to search. "11" is a place holder because I know what column contains my question. "& ":" & "K"" is another placeholder, it is supposed to concatenate with SUBSTITUTE() to make the range "'Pre Survey Data'!K:K". It does that successfully but Sheets doesn't read what is returned as a range.

Am I using the right formula?

Am I misunderstanding how formulas in sheets/excel work?

Please help :(

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see what you see. We don't know your data, your layout or your end goal. So while your post makes perfect sense to you, I'm sure, for those of us "out here"—well, not so much. I suggest that you share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it, or a representative sample from it). It is the most efficient and effective way to "help us help you."

Comment: @ErikTyler fair enough! I was trying to exclude screenshots for the sake of anonymity. But I do see your point! I included a copy with some changed values. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I may not have been clear enough. Images are of limited help, since a volunteer contributor here would have to start a new sheet and manually enter your data before they could even begin helping you, which is a big deterrent. I encourage you to share a link to a spreadsheet (the very one from which you drew the two images), setting the link's permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that people can test solutions right in the sheet and leave successful ones for you. It would also help if you manually enter the results you want to see a formula produce.

Comment: @ErikTyler okay third times the charm. Heres a link with editor permissions to the mock up spreadsheet. I added a comment with specifically what I want and what I'm expecting. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ozd4gRYg6RYMh_Jq0-0rYUvZ36P2LoxaPT7CX6xwOEI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at your linked sheet. Your question as illustrated in 'Table Data' Row 32 represents something that has virtually nothing in common with the data and layout above it, which contains merged cells, answers that are not exact within the form responses, responses such as "Not Listed" and "Null" which are not clear as to whether those are literal response labels or not, other answer choices that contain parenthetical score values — and none of the questions or answers for which are reflected in your sheet.

That said, I will answer the specific (and seemingly unrelated) question you've asked given the Row-32 information, your note, and nothing else.

Delete 'Table Data'!C32 and replace it with the following:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTA(QUERY(FILTER(FILTER('Pre Survey Data'!A:Z,'Pre Survey Data'!A:A<>"",ROW('Pre Survey Data'!A:A)>1),'Pre Survey Data'!1:1=A32),"Select * WHERE Col1 = '"&B32&"'")))`

The data is `FILTER`ed twice: once to get all populated rows, and once to limit to only the column which has the exact string (spaces, punctuation and all) listed in A32, and only data from Row 2 down.

`QUERY` then rules out all entries in that column that are not an exact match for the string in B32.

`COUNTA` counts the remaining results of the `QUERY`.

Comment: You're welcome. There are other ways to handle the kinds of layout you have above Row 32. But if that is something you're interested in, I recommend that you add enough data to realistically represent every facet shown in both sheets (i.e., if you want to see grade and gender, make sure you have at least those two questions as they are in your real sheet along with enough data to work with), indicate how the merged-cell labels will uniquely "find" column header questions, and then submit a new, separate post with that information. Of course, if you're all set already, great!